# Why does opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'path') work but opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"') doesn't as an option to Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, selenium-webdriver, path, selenium4

I have realized of something very weird when trying to deploy a `chrome driver` using `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory` from the user on `Python 3.9.7`, see below:

If you compile the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+r'C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

You get successfully a chrome driver instance using the corresponding `--user-data-dir` and `--profile-directory`:

[image: preview1]

Now, **after killing all chrome driver instances using the following code on** `cmd`:

```
taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe
```

And then compiling **this** other code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

path = input('Introduce YOUR profile path:')

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

For finally typing: `C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` as input

**You get this error**:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: Could not remove old devtools port
> file. Perhaps the given user-data-dir at
> "C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"
> is still attached to a running Chrome or Chromium process

Why does that happen?

Isn't `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"')` a valid way of passing this user data path:

`path = C:\Users\ResetStoreX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` ?

Comment: What is the actual difference between the *final string value* given to add_arguments? Nothing else matters or is relevant to the immediate A-B.

Comment: The difference is that the second code will be used for creating a program that will do some automated work for the user, after providing the profile path of chrome browser. @user2864740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was creating a syntax error with `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'"{path}"')`, so I changed it for `opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'{path}')`, the improved code would be the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

opt = Options() #the variable that will store the selenium options

path = input('Introduce YOUR profile path:')

opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir='+fr'{path}') #Add the user data path as an argument in selenium Options
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default') #Add the profile directory as an argument in selenium Options
s = Service('C:/Users/ResetStoreX/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=opt) 
driver.get('https://opensea.io/login?referrer=%2Faccount')
```

After compiling this code, the program will run without throwing any errors and get the same result as the first code shown in this post.